# adding bing maps in arm template azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I want to add a bing map resource to my arm template, however I get this  error :

```
"STATUS  BadRequest
STATUS MESSAGE  {
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed",
    "message": "User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'Offer with PublisherId: bingmaps and OfferId: bingmapsapiforenterprise not found.
                If this offer has been created recently, please allow up to 30 minutes for this offer to be available for Purchase. If error persists, contact support.'"
  }
}
PROVISIONING STATE  Failed
"
```

**here is part of my code :**

```
"resources": [
        {
            "name": "bingmapsARM",
            "type": "Microsoft.BingMaps/mapApis",
            "apiVersion": "2016-08-18",
            "location": "westus",
            "plan": {
                "publisher": "bingmaps",
                "product": "bingmapsapiforenterprise",
                "promotionCode": null,
                "name": "internal1"
            }
        },
```

Any help is much appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what I got from the portal:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.BingMaps/mapApis",
    "apiVersion": "2016-08-18",
    "name": "yyy",
    "location": "xxx",
    "plan": {
        "publisher": "bingmaps",
        "product": "mapapis",
        "name": "public1",
        "promotionCode": ""
    },
    "properties": {}
}
```

Comment: much thank you, it worked I would really like to know how did you get that!?

Comment: by creating a new bingmaps instance and then looking at the deployment that got created. also if this worked you should accept the answer ;)